# Type declaration in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types

I need to create a class which is basically a list containing only timestamps. Below is the `TimeStamp` trait:

```
trait TimeStamp[T <: Comparable[T]] extends Comparable[TimeStamp[T]]
{
def getTimeStamp:T;
def compareTo(to:TimeStamp[T]) =this.getTimeStamp.compareTo(to.getTimeStamp) 
}
```

`TimeStamp` is comparable. And the `getTimeStamp` return type is also comparable. It can be `Long` or `Date` for example. An example implementation of above trait is:

```
class FileTimeStamp(file:File) extends TimeStamp[Date] 
{
  val time:Long = file.lastModified();
  val date:Date = new Date(time);
  override def getTimeStamp:Date = date;
  def getFile:File = file;
}
```

Now the issue is I want to have a class called `TimeList` with no parameters. It can only take `TimeStamps` to be added in list.

```
class TimeList[T] extends ArrayList[TimeStamp[????]]
```

What should be my `????` above. Ideally I would want something like `[T <: Comparable[T]]`. i.e. a `Long` or `Date` or whatever a `TimeStamp` type is.

Comment: the `T` on `TimeList` is wrong?

Comment: That is the question :) basically how should be my class declaration of TiemList.

Comment: If you lower bound `T` to `Comparable[T]` your code works fine. What do you not like about this solution?

Comment: That i need to mention the type. I would want user to write val j:TimeList[FileTimeStamp] rather than val j:TimeList[Date]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class TimeList[T <: Comparable[T]] extends ArrayList[TimeStamp[T]]
```

EDIT: given your comment, you could do

```
class TimeList[T <: TimeStamp[_]] extends ArrayList[T]
```

but this type is going to be harder to use.

Comment: Then i need to mention the type. I would want user to write val j:TimeList[FileTimeStamp] rather than val j:TimeList[Date] . WIth the solution above, I will have to declare it as TimeList[Date]